# docker image (nodejs app) on GCP returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSHED (works locally)

Tags: node.js, docker, google-compute-engine

I have create a docker image from a nodejs app. I want to start a VM instance with the docker image on GCP Compute Egine Instance.

When I test the image locally and I navigate with my browser to http://localhost:8000, it works. So I don't think there is something wrong with my docker image.

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -d <username>/<docker-file>
```

I have pushed the docker image to google container repository with the following commands:

```
docker tag <username>/<docker-file> gcr.io/<project-id>/<docker-file>
docker push gcr.io/<project-id>/<docker-file>
```

Now, when I add the URL (gcr.io/project-id/docker-file) to a VM instance, and I wait untill the instance is running, I get an error when I navigate to http://[instance_external_ip]:8000, I get the error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I have set a firewall rule to allow ingress traffic on port tcp = 8000 and IP range 0.0.0.0/0.

Am I missing something?

**Edit:**

My dockerfile

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/nodejs

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: @prithajnath: I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How/when do you start running the docker?
Could you run this command

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -d gcr.io/<project-id>/<docker-file>:latest
```

And then try to confirm that it's running locally first using

```
curl localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile you expose 8080 not 8000.

Did you check that your container is running on the instance?
tried to curl/telnet it too?

Comment: I changed the port, in my real docker file it says 8000. And no, how can I check a container is running on an instance? Just SSH => open it => docker container cmd?

Comment: ssh the instance, run  - docker ps -a . you should see the container state

Comment: I see 2 container ID's, but not the container I installed. Mmmh... I think I'm going to recreate the instance.